# Load UICollectionViewCell outside screen?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm using:

```
cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath]
```

for creating the cell of an UICollectionView. Each cell is the size of the screen. I need to load the previous and next cell but both are outside of the screen, so cellForItemAtIndexPath is not called. I need this configuration:

[image]

is it posible to call cellForItemAtIndexPath for the red cells? Even if they are not being displayed?

Comment: Why are you using a collection view if the cells are equal to screen size? What are you trying to achieve? You can create a paging `UIScrollView` and just populate the screens as you need them without introducing the complexity of a `UICollectionView`.

Comment: I have like 100 items. And a UICollectionView inside each cell (to swipe right and left) and I need to reuse them. But I need to load the previous and next cell because I download images from a server,